# TextField with inputmask, how to check if is empty?

Tags: qt, qml, textfield, qtquickcontrols2

How do I check is a Textfield is empty, when I use an inputmask on it?

Ex: I have a textfield with this mask: "099.999.999-90"

When I get the `textfield.text`, I get this: "..-".

This is making it impossible to do this comparison:

```
if( textfield.text === "") {}
```

I tried compare to textfield.inputmask, but that doesn't work either, because the value of `textfield.inputmask` is: "099.999.999-90"

and this comparison:

```
if( textfield.text === textfield.inputmask) {}
```

returns false.

Is there some solution for this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned input mask to TextField, it would be better to check for acceptableInput property. If acceptableInput is false, then TextField contents doesn't conform to input mask, so it can be considered as "empty" as well.